# Error when running signed APK with Proguard

Tags: android, apk, proguard, android-proguard

My app is crashing upon launching the signed apk version with Proguard enabled. Note that in regular debug mode, the app does not crash.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: orbyt.horizon, PID: 21671
       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:688)
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:171)
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:72)
           at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:359)
           ... 
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field LINK in class La/a/a/c/a/i; (declaration of 'a.a.a.c.a.i' appears in /data/app/orbyt.horizon-1/base.apk)
           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
           at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:685)
           at
```

Now, if I were to guess I would say that Proguard is obfuscating a few classes that it shouldnt be. So how do you go about debugging this?

Here is my `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

# Retrofit 2.X
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Butterknife

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

# Glide specific rules #
# https://github.com/bumptech/glide

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}


## Retrolambda specific rules ##

# as per official recommendation: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#proguard
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

# OkHttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**


#JodaTime
# These aren't necessary if including joda-convert, but
# most people aren't, so it's helpful to include it.
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.FromString
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.ToString

#twitter4j
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

#google
-dontwarn com.google.**

#okio
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn okio.**

#misc
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum
-keep  class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** {*;}
-keep  class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.** {*;}
-keep  class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** {*;}
-keep class libcore.** { *; }
```

So what might be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at mappings.txt file generated by proguard to see what class `a/a/a/c/a/i` maps to before obfuscation?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was debugging this last night and after googling I did end up looking through the mappings.txt file. I just generated another signed apk and took a look at the new mappings.txt, but searching the file for that string does not turn up anything. I've read somewhere that when using the mappings.txt file, the retrace.bat file is sometimes needed, is this a case like that? What would I need to do with the retrace executable in regards to the mapping.txt file? As a side note, I did just get a version working (see answer), but would still like to learn how to debug it.

Comment: Usually you would use the retrace tool to process a stack trace of a crash to get all the original symbols and line numbers back into it.  But a manual scan of mappings.txt is usually good enough to turn up what symbols are missing.

Comment: Ah ok. Odd then that I didnt see anything. I saw many classes from the package that was causing the issue (which I noted in my answer below), but nothing that was matching the stacktrace. I'll have to look into using the retrace tool a bit. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was with [JRAW](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW), adding the following lines to my `proguard-rules.pro` file seems to have fixed the issue:

```
#jraw
-dontwarn net.dean.**
-keep class net.dean.** {*;}
```